# Linking using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which I display when someone clicks a button using the `onclick=""`, and if they submit it, and the information is all correct, then they are redirected to the another page, however if the information is incorrect then the errors are displayed. My problem is people always have to click the button to show the form to even show the error, is there a way I can do `mysite/index.php#` show_form_by_default Or something that I can redirect to so that they can view the form without having to click it assuming there are errors in it.

```
 <a id="button1" class="submit" onclick="$('#form').show('slow'); $(this).hide('slow');">Form</a></p>

    <div class="box" id="form" style="text-align: center; display: none;">


<form class="notice" action="form.php" method="post">
    form stuff here
</form> 
    </div>
```

Basically if there a way to display the form via the URL by default?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this, but any possible solution will depend on your code, which you haven't posted.

Comment: Sorry just posted my code @MikeW

Comment: would you like to work on jquery Modal

Comment: @user1145009 I prefer not to. I'm just wondering if there is a way I can redirect it to index.php?#show_form or something. I have the redirection at the moment to display, but they have to click the form button for the errors to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash.toLowerCase();
        if(hash == "#show_form_by_default")
        {
            $('#button1').hide();
            $('#form').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you want to monitor for changes in the hash (i.e a link on the same page that sets the hash without navigating away you can use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(checkHash);   
    var oldHash = null;
    function checkHash()
    {
        var hash = window.location.hash.toLowerCase();
        if(oldHash != hash)
        {
            if(hash == "#show_form_by_default")
            {
                $('#button1').hide();
                $('#form').show();
            }
            oldHash = hash;
        }
        setTimeout(checkHash, 100);
    }
</script>
```

Modify the timeout interval to be as long or as short as you like depending on how often you want it to check for changes.

Comment: My entire page is blank now :P @Neaox

Comment: can you create a js fiddle showing exactly what code you have?

Comment: I basically copy pasted what you gave me. And my entire page is blank, but if I remove the code then the page is displayed again, maybe it's something to do with the hash?

Comment: NVM, I made a bonehead mistake! :P My apologies! Thank you good sir.

Comment: last question, so to display it, I would basically go index.php#show_form_by_default  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work. However if you enter the hash on an already loaded page it will not work, if you wish to do this you will need to monitor for changes in the hash, the reason for this is that changing the hash without relocating to a different location/page does not re-trigger the document ready event.

Comment: If you need help on writing code to monitor changes to the hash let me know.

Comment: I have added an example for monitoring of hash, just in case.